# WSDL + PHP + Java (SOAP)

Tags: java, php, soap, wsdl

I am working with Java and Php. I'm calling the Java services via WSDLs from what i generate php-stubs with the tool WSDL2PHP. 
Everything works fine until now. I've added a new method to my java service and re-generated the php-stub. In the php-stub the method is available but when i call the service i'm getting the following error:

```
SoapFault: Function ("myFunction") is not a valid method for this service
```

I've tried a lot and googled a lot, and it worked before. My old methods in the same service are always callable and i can run them bu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the SOAPClient caches your WSDL files. You can disable this feature using:

```
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled = "0";
```

Beware, this has a performance impact. But on your development machine this wont affect things.